# Dlang kxml getCData usage

Tags: xml, methods, type-conversion, d, kxml

I'm using in my project such library for XML parsing:

https://github.com/opticron/kxml/blob/master/source/kxml/xml.d

Here is my example code:

```
void main()
{
    string xmlstring = cast(string)read("test.xml");
    XmlNode newdoc = xmlstring.readDocument();
    XmlNode[]  searchlist = newdoc.parseXPath("//instancesSet/item");

    foreach(list, searchlist)
    {
    string test = list.parseXPath("//instanceId").getCData();
    writeln(test);
    }
}
```

And it don't want to compile:

```
$ dub
Performing "debug" build using dmd for x86_64.
kxml 1.0.0: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
test ~master: building configuration "application"...
source/app.d(23,56): Error: no property 'getCData' for type 'XmlNode[]'
dmd failed with exit code 1.
```

When I'm using `foreach` loop I thought it is taking only one value from whole array. So if that is array of `XmlNode[]` variable, only one from it should be just `XmlNode` (not array).

Why it still see there array? How to use `getCData()` method to clear variable from tags and put it to `string`?

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, `list` is in fact an `XmlNode`, but its `parseXPath()` returns `XmlNode[]`. If you want to work only with first result of XPath query in each `list`, just add `[0]`.

```d
string test = list.parseXPath("//instanceId")[0].getCData();
```